# Why doesn't my InStr Work?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using this expression in a calculated field InStr(-1,"Beejal Larkin"," ")

When I submit it, each field is filled with #Func!. I don't understand why this is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means there is an error in your function.

Comment: why -1 ? what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably read:

```
 =InStr(1,"Beejal Larkin"," ")
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I assumed -1 would just read it all... Thanks